# Create a new table with the percentage quantity amount of individual counterparties compared to the total quantity

Tags: r, sum, data.table, percentage

I have the following data table:

```
dt.data <- structure(list(delivMonth = c("2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", 
"2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", 
"2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", 
"2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", 
"2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", 
"2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", 
"2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-04", "2024-05", 
"2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", 
"2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", 
"2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", 
"2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", 
"2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", 
"2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-05", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", 
"2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", 
"2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", 
"2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", 
"2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", 
"2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", "2024-06", 
"2024-06", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", 
"2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", 
"2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", 
"2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", 
"2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", 
"2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-07", 
"2024-07", "2024-07", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", 
"2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", 
"2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", 
"2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", 
"2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", 
"2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", 
"2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-08", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", 
"2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", 
"2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", 
"2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", 
"2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", 
"2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", 
"2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-09", "2024-10", "2024-10", 
"2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", 
"2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", 
"2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", 
"2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", 
"2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", "2024-10", 
"2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", 
"2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", 
"2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", 
"2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", 
"2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-11", 
"2024-11", "2024-11", "2024-12", "2024-12", "2024-12", "2024-12", 
"2024-12", "2024-12", "2024-12", "2024-12", "2024-12", "2024-12", 
"2024-12", "2024-12", "2024-12", "2024-12", "2024-12", "2024-12", 
"2024-12", "2024-12", "2024-12"), quantity = c(-3600, 1440, 0, 
-34560, 5760, 0, 7200, 3600, 720, 993.6, 1800, 734.4, 720, -13680, 
18252, -842.4, 2880, -3600, -2160, 3600, -3600, 43272, 0, 3600, 
-1420.56, 20534.4, 835.2, 345.6, 2160, -7200, -14400, 5040, 720, 
-10800, 360, 3600, 1980, 720, -3720, 1488, 0, -35712, 5952, 0, 
-7440, 744, 1026.72, 1860, 758.88, 744, -4464, 18860.4, -870.48, 
2976, -2232, 3720, -3720, 33554.4, 0, -1467.91, 15266.88, 863.04, 
357.12, 2232, -7440, -3720, 5208, 744, 372, 3720, 2046, 744, 
-3600, 1440, 0, -34560, 5760, 0, -7200, 720, 993.6, 1800, 734.4, 
720, -720, 18252, -842.4, 2880, -2160, 3600, -3600, 32472, 0, 
-1420.56, 11174.4, 835.2, 345.6, 2160, -7200, -3600, 5040, 720, 
360, 3600, 1980, 720, -3720, 1488, -3720, -35712, 5952, 0, -3720, 
3720, 744, 1026.72, 1860, 758.88, 744, -744, 18860.4, -870.48, 
2976, 0, -2232, 3720, -3720, 32810.4, 0, -1467.91, 11546.88, 
863.04, 357.12, -1488, -7440, -7440, 5208, 744, 372, 3720, 3720, 
2046, 744, -3720, 1488, -3720, -35712, 5952, 0, -3720, 3720, 
744, 1026.72, 1860, 758.88, 744, -744, 18860.4, -870.48, 2976, 
0, -2232, 3720, -3720, 32810.4, 0, -1467.91, 11546.88, 863.04, 
357.12, -1488, -7440, -7440, 5208, 744, 372, 3720, 3720, 2046, 
744, -3600, 1440, -3600, -34560, 5760, 0, -3600, 3600, 720, 993.6, 
1800, 734.4, 720, -4320, 18252, -842.4, 2880, 0, -2160, 3600, 
-3600, 31752, 0, -1420.56, 14774.4, 835.2, 345.6, -1440, -7200, 
-7200, 5040, 720, 360, 3600, 3600, 1980, 720, 35015, 1490, 0, 
21605, 5960, 0, 4470, 1028.1, 1862.5, 759.9, 745, -2980, 18885.75, 
-871.65, 2980, 3725, -3725, 32854.5, 0, -1469.89, 12307.4, 864.2, 
357.6, 12665, -7450, -3725, 5215, 745, 372.5, 3725, 2048.75, 
745, 33840, 1440, 0, 20880, 5760, 0, 4320, 993.6, 1800, 734.4, 
720, -7200, 18252, -842.4, 2880, 3600, -3600, 31752, 0, -1420.56, 
11894.4, 835.2, 345.6, 12240, -7200, -3600, 5040, 720, 360, 3600, 
1980, 720, 34968, 1488, 0, 21576, 5952, 0, 4464, 1026.72, 1860, 
758.88, 744, -22320, 18860.4, -870.48, 2976, 3720, -3720, 32810.4, 
0), counterparty = c("Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", 
"CEZ (CZ)", "CEZ (CZ)", "CEZ (CZ)", "DXT Commodities (CH)", "DXT Commodities (CH)", 
"EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EnBW (DE)", 
"Energie AG (AT)", "Energie Klagenfurt (AT)", "Engie (FR)", "Engie (FR)", 
"Gunvor (CH)", "Gunvor (CH)", "HSE (SI)", "Mercuria (CH)", "Mercuria (CH)", 
"OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "RAG (AT)", 
"RWE (DE)", "RWE (DE)", "RWE (DE)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", 
"SEFE (GB)", "SEFE (GB)", "Shell (GB)", "Uniper (DE)", "Uniper (DE)", 
"WINGAS (DE)", "WINGAS (DE)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", 
"CEZ (CZ)", "CEZ (CZ)", "CEZ (CZ)", "DXT Commodities (CH)", "EDF Trading (GB)", 
"EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EnBW (DE)", "Energie AG (AT)", 
"Energie Klagenfurt (AT)", "Engie (FR)", "Engie (FR)", "Gunvor (CH)", 
"HSE (SI)", "Mercuria (CH)", "Mercuria (CH)", "OMV Gas M&T (AT)", 
"OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "RAG (AT)", "RWE (DE)", "RWE (DE)", "RWE (DE)", 
"RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "SEFE (GB)", "SEFE (GB)", 
"Uniper (DE)", "Uniper (DE)", "WINGAS (DE)", "WINGAS (DE)", "Axpo (CH)", 
"Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "CEZ (CZ)", "CEZ (CZ)", "CEZ (CZ)", 
"DXT Commodities (CH)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", 
"EDF Trading (GB)", "EnBW (DE)", "Energie AG (AT)", "Energie Klagenfurt (AT)", 
"Engie (FR)", "Engie (FR)", "Gunvor (CH)", "HSE (SI)", "Mercuria (CH)", 
"Mercuria (CH)", "OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "RAG (AT)", 
"RWE (DE)", "RWE (DE)", "RWE (DE)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", 
"SEFE (GB)", "SEFE (GB)", "Uniper (DE)", "Uniper (DE)", "WINGAS (DE)", 
"WINGAS (DE)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "CEZ (CZ)", 
"CEZ (CZ)", "CEZ (CZ)", "DXT Commodities (CH)", "DXT Commodities (CH)", 
"EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EnBW (DE)", 
"Energie AG (AT)", "Energie Klagenfurt (AT)", "Engie (FR)", "Engie (FR)", 
"Gunvor (CH)", "Gunvor (CH)", "HSE (SI)", "Mercuria (CH)", "Mercuria (CH)", 
"OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "RAG (AT)", "RWE (DE)", 
"RWE (DE)", "RWE (DE)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "SEFE (GB)", 
"SEFE (GB)", "Uniper (DE)", "Uniper (DE)", "Vitol (CH)", "WINGAS (DE)", 
"WINGAS (DE)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "CEZ (CZ)", 
"CEZ (CZ)", "CEZ (CZ)", "DXT Commodities (CH)", "DXT Commodities (CH)", 
"EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EnBW (DE)", 
"Energie AG (AT)", "Energie Klagenfurt (AT)", "Engie (FR)", "Engie (FR)", 
"Gunvor (CH)", "Gunvor (CH)", "HSE (SI)", "Mercuria (CH)", "Mercuria (CH)", 
"OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "RAG (AT)", "RWE (DE)", 
"RWE (DE)", "RWE (DE)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "SEFE (GB)", 
"SEFE (GB)", "Uniper (DE)", "Uniper (DE)", "Vitol (CH)", "WINGAS (DE)", 
"WINGAS (DE)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "CEZ (CZ)", 
"CEZ (CZ)", "CEZ (CZ)", "DXT Commodities (CH)", "DXT Commodities (CH)", 
"EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EnBW (DE)", 
"Energie AG (AT)", "Energie Klagenfurt (AT)", "Engie (FR)", "Engie (FR)", 
"Gunvor (CH)", "Gunvor (CH)", "HSE (SI)", "Mercuria (CH)", "Mercuria (CH)", 
"OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "RAG (AT)", "RWE (DE)", 
"RWE (DE)", "RWE (DE)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "SEFE (GB)", 
"SEFE (GB)", "Uniper (DE)", "Uniper (DE)", "Vitol (CH)", "WINGAS (DE)", 
"WINGAS (DE)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "CEZ (CZ)", 
"CEZ (CZ)", "CEZ (CZ)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", 
"EDF Trading (GB)", "EnBW (DE)", "Energie AG (AT)", "Energie Klagenfurt (AT)", 
"Engie (FR)", "Engie (FR)", "Gunvor (CH)", "Mercuria (CH)", "Mercuria (CH)", 
"OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "RAG (AT)", "RWE (DE)", 
"RWE (DE)", "RWE (DE)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "SEFE (GB)", 
"SEFE (GB)", "Uniper (DE)", "Uniper (DE)", "WINGAS (DE)", "WINGAS (DE)", 
"Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "CEZ (CZ)", "CEZ (CZ)", 
"CEZ (CZ)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", 
"EnBW (DE)", "Energie AG (AT)", "Energie Klagenfurt (AT)", "Engie (FR)", 
"Engie (FR)", "Gunvor (CH)", "Mercuria (CH)", "Mercuria (CH)", 
"OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "RAG (AT)", "RWE (DE)", 
"RWE (DE)", "RWE (DE)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "RWE (GB)", "SEFE (GB)", 
"SEFE (GB)", "Uniper (DE)", "Uniper (DE)", "WINGAS (DE)", "WINGAS (DE)", 
"Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "Axpo (CH)", "CEZ (CZ)", "CEZ (CZ)", 
"CEZ (CZ)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", "EDF Trading (GB)", 
"EnBW (DE)", "Energie AG (AT)", "Energie Klagenfurt (AT)", "Engie (FR)", 
"Engie (FR)", "Gunvor (CH)", "Mercuria (CH)", "Mercuria (CH)", 
"OMV Gas M&T (AT)", "OMV Gas M&T (AT)"), marketArea = c("CEGH", 
"THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", 
"TTF", "TTF", "CEGH", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", 
"CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", 
"CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "CEGH", 
"THE", "TTF", "TTF", "CEGH", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "CEGH", 
"CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", 
"THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", 
"THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "CEGH", "CEGH", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "CEGH", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "TTF", "TTF", "CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", 
"THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", 
"TTF", "TTF", "CEGH", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", 
"CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", 
"THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "TTF", "TTF", "CEGH", "TTF", 
"CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", 
"THE", "TTF", "TTF", "CEGH", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "TTF", 
"CEGH", "CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "TTF", "TTF", 
"CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", 
"THE", "TTF", "TTF", "CEGH", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "CEGH", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "TTF", "CEGH", 
"CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", "CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "CEGH", 
"CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", 
"TTF", "CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE", "TTF", 
"CEGH", "THE", "TTF", "TTF", "CEGH", "CEGH", "CEGH", "THE", "THE", 
"CEGH", "TTF", "CEGH", "THE")), row.names = c(NA, -300L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"))
```

I have calculated the total sum of quantity with `sum(dt.data$quantity, na.rm = TRUE)`.

Now I want to create a new table `dt.percentage` that lists the percentage share/amount of the total quantity for each `counterparty`. The sum across the new table should add up to 100%, representing the total quantity.

The new table should now only consist of the columns `counterparty` and `percentage`, which shows a percentage value for each counterparty with respect to the 100%.

How could this work in R? Is there a base R-function that works here?

Comment: Your recent questions leave the impression: (1) You have not completed a data wrangling intro (in R); (2) time and effort you have invested to look up and understand similiar questions dealing with basic tasks is not adequate; (3) You are not aware of the fact that SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: `dt[, .N, counterparty][, N := 100 * N / sum(N)]`. This is a classic grouping operation, see the dupe links for many ways to do this. If this code and the dupe-links don't give you enough context and/or do not resolve your question, please add the code you attempt, its output, and what is not correct (or its warnings/errors); after that, @-ping me and we'll sort through the problems. Good luck!

Comment: @Friede - 
Sorry, but what is your problem? I don't use R very intensively and only occasionally for specific questions. Sometimes coding works well for me, sometimes I lack understanding and knowledge of all conceivable ``R ``packages and functions. I generally know how to use Stack Overflow and use it when I'm stuck and some possible ideas from other Stack Overflow posts don't lead to a solution. If it bothers you, you can simply ignore my posts!!! Have a nice day!